# Calculate var(X(1/2 - X)) knowinng Var(X) = 4 and E(X) = 1

Tags: probability, statistics

Here is the problem:
If E(X) = 1 and Var(X) = 4, calculate Var(X(1/2 - X)).
I was trying to solve it using several properties of Variance, but nothing helped.
Could you help me? Thx in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What you are trying to find is not determined purily by expectation and variance of $X$.

Comment: Verify whether the problem statement is correct.